# store ajax class in variable - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a php file `file.php` which returns

```
<ul class="class1">
    <li class="class2"><a href="#" rel="">file</a></li>
    <li class="class3"><a href="#" rel="">file</a></li>
</ul>
```

called by my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('#list').fileTree({ root: 'docs/',
                              script: 'file.php',
                              },
                        function(file) {
                                open(file);
                        });
});
</script>
```

to use inside `<div id="list">`

I want to store the returned class1, class2 and class3 (they varies) in seperate variabled in my javascript. How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to get an array of the classes.

Once the `ul` is inside `<div id="list">`, you can do this:

```
var classes = $('ul,li', '#list').map(function(i,v){
  return $(v).attr('class');
}).get();
```

You can also run `.map()` on the HTML string:

```
var html = '<ul class="class1"><li class="class2"><a href="#" rel="">file</a></li><li class="class3"><a href="#" rel="">file</a></li></ul>';

var classes = $(html).add('li', html).map(function(i, v) {
    return $(v).attr('class');
}).get();
```

In both cases, `classes` will be an array: `[class1, class2, class3]`.

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CRFft/

Comment: can u tell me how to get class on theis example http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/

Comment: @blasteralfred: The 1st block of code should work for you.  Try it.